# Azure Rest Api List container : Parameter Marker

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Hi Guys I am building a Client which Interact with Azure Storage Rest API.

I was going through documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/list-containers2:

And didn't understood the use of parameter prefix and marker which can be send along with Azure request.

It says:

prefix

> Optional. Filters the results to return only containers whose name
>   begins with the specified prefix.

marker

> Optional. A string value that identifies the portion of the list of
>   containers to be returned with the next listing operation. The
>   operation returns the NextMarker value within the response body if the
>   listing operation did not return all containers remaining to be listed
>   with the current page. The NextMarker value can be used as the value
>   for the marker parameter in a subsequent call to request the next page
>   of list items.
>
> The marker value is opaque to the client.

With Prefix, I think:

If i have dir structure:

```
file01.txt
images/image01.jpg
images/folder/image001.jpg
fightVideo/subFolder/current/video001.mpg
fightVideo/subFolder/current/video002.mpg
```

> If I give prefix container name as "fight". It should return
>   fightVideo.

But I am not sure.

And for Marker I don't understand whats its use?

> Please can someone explain the use of Prefix and Marker with examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In context of listing containers, if you specify `prefix` parameter it will list the containers names of which start with that prefix value. It has nothing to do with listing blobs.

[`List blobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/list-blobs) operation also supports this `prefix` parameter and when you specify this parameter, it will list the blobs names of which start with that prefix value.

So the example you have given is for listing blobs and when you specify `flight` as prefix there, you will get back `fightVideo/subFolder/current/video001.mpg` and `fightVideo/subFolder/current/video002.mpg` in response but not when you call list containers with this prefix.

Regarding `marker`, Kalyan's explanation is correct but let me add a little bit more to that.

Essentially Azure Storage Service is a shared service and you simply can't ask it to return all the results in one go (if we were to take an analogy from SQL world, you simply can't do `SELECT * FROM TABLE` kind of thing). Each request to the service is assigned a predefined timeout and the response would include the items fetched in that time + optionally a token if the service thinks that there's more data available. This token is called `continuation token`. In order to get the next set of items, you would need to pass this continuation token in the marker parameter in your next request.

Each call to storage service will try to return a predefined maximum number of items. For listing blob containers/blobs, this limit is 5000 items. For listing tables/entities, this limit is 1000 items. If there are more items in your account, then apart from this data storage service returns you a continuation token which tells you that there's more data available.

Please note that even though the limit is there but you can't always assume that you will get these number of records. Based on a number of conditions, it is quite possible that you don't get back any data but still receive a continuation token. So your code need to handle this condition as well.

Comment: I have a blob with millions of files and I want to check the last 5,000 blob names and modification time (as identified by LastModified attribute). Is there any way to do that without paging through many thousands of continuation tokens as I need to do that often (streaming IoT input)? I found conditional header `If-Modified-Since` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-conditional-headers-for-blob-service-operations) but not sure if that solves it. I can't believe that the REST endpoint makes this so hard.

Comment: Unfortunately you're out of luck. Unless you follow some naming convention for your blobs, you will need to iterate through the list and find last 5000 blobs. `If-Modified-Since` conditional header will also not help you as it is not applicable to blobs listing. One possible solution would be to import this list in Azure Search and then perform the search there.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately renaming is not an option as this is a production environment with many dependencies on the file name. One last option I could think of is storing the continuation tokens somewhere and always continue from the last retrieved? From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312065/azure-blob-storage-how-to-enumerate-blobs-in-long-running-and-recoverable-fashi) question I take it that the token should not change?

Comment: If you're planning to cache continuation token, then don't! It is an opaque property and should not be stored.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with caching. I would write it into e.g. SQL table and extract from it for the REST request e.g. via Azure function.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant by caching. You should NOT save the tokens in permanent storage like SQL table.

Comment: hm that sucks. I can see that some of the SDKs (e.g. Python) have methods for returning NextMarker but I wanted to be as generic and no-dependency like as possible. Still hard to believe that there is not a more elegant solutions.

Comment: Please take a look at Azure Search and Blob Storage integration especially indexing the metadata. I can’t think of a better solution than that.

Answer (score 1):

If there are too many blobs to be listed, then the response contains the NextMarker element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<EnumerationResults ServiceEndpoint="https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net">  
  <Prefix>string-value</Prefix>  
  <Marker>string-value</Marker>  
  <MaxResults>int-value</MaxResults>  
  <Containers>  
    <Container>  
      <Name>container-name</Name>  
      <Properties>  
        <Last-Modified>date/time-value</Last-Modified>  
        <Etag>etag</Etag>  
        <LeaseStatus>locked | unlocked</LeaseStatus>  
        <LeaseState>available | leased | expired | breaking | broken</LeaseState>  
        <LeaseDuration>infinite | fixed</LeaseDuration> 
        <PublicAccess>container | blob</PublicAccess>       
      </Properties>  
      <Metadata>  
        <metadata-name>value</metadata-name>  
      </Metadata>  
    </Container>  
  </Containers>  
  <NextMarker>marker-value</NextMarker>  
</EnumerationResults>
```

The REST API documentation mentions that the marker value can be used in a subsequent call to request the next set of list items.

You can imagine marker as a paginatator index.