# Azure Blob Storage: How to enumerate blobs in long-running and recoverable fashion?

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to enumerate possibly millions of blobs in a lengthy operation. From the [List Blobs documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/list-blobs), I'm still left with the following questions:

- What's the duration or expiration time of `NextMarker` value?
- Can I use the value of `NextMarker` on a different HTTPS connection? Possibly from another machine (IP address)?
- Can I call the List Blobs API multiple times with the same value for `NextMarker`? Will they all return the next page? (I'm ok if pages may differ on each call - I don't need 100% reliability).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/enumerating-blob-resources), NextMarker is just a string which stands for the next blob to enumerate. So the answers to your questions are:

1. There is no expiration time of NextMarker value.
2. You can use it on a a different HTTPS connection or from another machine (IP address).
3. You can call the List Blobs API multiple times with the same value for NextMarker, they will all return the next page as long as you didn't change the content of the container between two List Blobs requests.

Comment: I see that, but the doc I referenced says: "Note that the value of NextMarker should be treated as opaque." Ideally MS should state the features. But giving you seem to be an authoritative source, I will mark this a solution. Thanks!

Comment: What I mentioned above is just the current behavior of Azure Blob Storage service, but given the REST API doc doesn't announce the behavior clearly and the official doc says "Note that the value of NextMarker should be treated as opaque", it's possible that service may change the implementation in the future.